# jquery and Animation.css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

I am writing a function to slideInText from left, show it on screen for 5 secs and slideOutLeft from left using animation.css plugin. This is not working the way I wanted.

I have an array that stores values of different Ids and I will need to pass these Id's each time to an api call. for every api call I make I will get some 5 values and I will need to display these values one after another and then make an api call with new id value. this is a continuous process. that should happen. can anyone help where am i going wrong?

Comment: I suppose that's because $.each executes immediately and the
  setInterval(AnimateOneByOne, 2000); line does not block the thread. thats why animation would kind of not seem working, tho if you give fiddle I may look further for problem

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen I have attached the Fiddle. Please look into it !

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your post's comment section, You would like your animations to have in an order, in a queue. I have created an example below:

[See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngxL81vw/11/)

You might work on **function AnimateOneOnly(dataPair)** that I leave you for. I couldn't able to load animate.css on fiddle tho. If you counter problems with animate.css please mention it on this post's comment section. (And please fiddle with working animate.css on)

**JS**

```
var dataArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var dataFromServer = [
    { 'name': 'Value1', 'position': 1608.55434},
    { 'name': 'Value2', 'position': 60.66757},  
    { 'name': 'Value3', 'position': 1608.55434},
    { 'name': 'Value4', 'position': 60.66757},  
];

function AnimateOneOnly(dataPair){
    if(dataPair.position != null){
        $("#text")
            .text(dataPair.name)
            //.addClass('slideInLeft');
        $("#value")
            .text(dataPair.position.toFixed(2))
            //.addClass('slideInLeft');
        //$(".animation0").removeClass('slideInLeft');
    }  
}

var showTextTimerSet    = null;
var textDelay           = 2000;
var queue               = [];
function callThisWhenReceiveData(data) {
    queue.push.apply(queue, data);
    if (showTextTimerSet == null) {
        var showTextFunc = function () {
            AnimateOneOnly(queue.shift());
            if (queue.length != 0) {
                showTextTimerSet = setTimeout(showTextFunc, textDelay);
            }
            else {
                showTextTimerSet = null;
            }
        }
        showTextTimerSet = setTimeout(showTextFunc, textDelay);
    }
}

function demo_fakeSource() {
    callThisWhenReceiveData(dataFromServer);
    var timer = 2000 * (3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
    $('#demo').append('<li>Next: ' + timer + ' Current queue: ' + queue.length + '</li>');

    setTimeout(demo_fakeSource,timer);
}

demo_fakeSource();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="text" class="animated"></div>
<div id="value" class="animated"></div>
<ol id="demo">

</ol>
```

Comment: I did add the animate.min.css cdn to the fiddle.

Comment: I am adding the fiddle with animate.min.css . If you check the animation only works for the first time https://jsfiddle.net/ngxL81vw/12/